# Обновление таблицы и ошибка String or binary data would be truncated

Tags: sql, sql-server, update

```
if object_id('tempdb..#NT')is not null drop table #NT

DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(12) 
SET @name = 'ELSETI\';

CREATE TABLE #NT (role char(50) NOT NULL,
userr_id int,
rolee_id int,
loginn_name char(50) NOT NULL,
workk_name char(50) NOT NULL
)

insert into #NT
SELECT @name+''+psss.login_name as role,ppp.user_id,ppp.role_id,psss.login_name,psss.work_name 
FROM security_role_user ppp
INNER JOIN _users psss ON psss.user_id = ppp.user_id where ppp.role_id='68'
```

Вот обновление значений в таблице [_users]

```
UPDATE
   [_users]
SET
    [_users].login_name = Table_B.role
FROM
    [_users]
    INNER JOIN #NT AS Table_B
        ON [_users].user_id = Table_B.userr_id
WHERE
    Table_B.rolee_id='68'
```

но появляется ошибка  Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 23 String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.

содержимое #NT

[image: содержимое #NT]

[image: содержимое _users]

содержимое _users

Comment: Попробуй задать `DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(50)` (размер как у `role`, в выражении для значения которого переменная используется). И подумай, не надо ли в таблице использовать NCHAR вместо CHAR.

Comment: нет, не помогло

Comment: `[_users].login_name = LEFT(Table_B.role, 50)`, если такое устраивает, конечно же

Comment: Причину ошибки нашел. длина строки login_name в таблице _users была длиной 20 символов. в итоге получалось что добавив ELSETI\  некоторые записи становились более 20 символов. проблема решилась увеличением длины символов которую можно записать в колонку